# Java swing trying to understand it better

Tags: java, swing

So I am trying to make a menu in swing of 8 functions. This code i have right now.

```
 import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Menu extends JFrame {
    public Menu(){
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
       @Override
       public void run(){
           Menu menu = new Menu();
           menu.setVisible(true);
       }
    });



    }
    private void init() {
        setTitle("Group 2");
        setSize(300, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton quitButton = new JButton("E(X)it");
        quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        createLayout(quitButton);


        JButton nameAsk = new JButton("What is your name?");
        nameAsk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            }
        });
        createLayout(nameAsk);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg){
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);
        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(arg[0]));
        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(arg[0]));
   }

  }
```

The problem is when i add one more button the other one goes away. I think its on top of other button but i am confused now.

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting your layout each time you add a component using your createLayout method. You should only be setting your layout once, and adding components that layout one by one.

Comment: JFrame uses a BorderLayout by default, consider using a different layout manager. See [Laying it components within a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/) for some more ideas